# Javascript file could not be loaded and executed in eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jsp

I have created a dynamic web project in eclipse. The WebContent structure Image is mentioned below.....

[WebContent Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTnNH.png)

My Login.jsp code is as follows.

=========================================================

```
enter code here

<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
 <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
    <body>
     <form id="loginForm" action="Login_Controller" method="post">
       <div id = "signin_box">
          <h3 align="center">Login to continue..</h3>

         <div class = "div_s">
             <input type = "text" id = "UserName" name = "UserName"                                                            
         </div>

         <div class = "div_s">
             <input type = "password" id = "Password" name = "Password">
         </div>

         <div>
             <input type = "submit" id = "submit_Btn" value = "Login">
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
 </body>


enter code here
```

===================================================================

## And the JavaScript.js code contains..

```
    $(document).ready(function(){       
       alert("Script Ready");
    });
```

==============================

When I run the Login.jsp page.....Ideally an alert should get displayed saying "Script Ready". But it dosen't work. The Javascript file is not getting loaded.
Can can help in identifying what could be the problem?

When the web page is loaded on to the browser...I see something like this on the url....[url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpXa6.png)

Comment: Have you checked you developers console? Are there any errors?

Comment: Hi @u_mulder there is an error on the developer console.....

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ JavaScript.js:30
jquery.validate.js:15 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery.validate.js:15(anonymous function) @ jquery.validate.js:17

Comment: This is what I saw on the developer console

Comment: Hi @u_mulder I have got the solution.......You should put the references to the jquery scripts first. Then put your actual Javascript reference.

 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
**This line should be at the last**
**<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript.js"></script>**